# How can I print just the name of the camera and not the full structure?

Tags: python, scripting, camera

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
activecamera = bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].camera

if activecamera == None:
    print("No Active Camera Selected")
else:
    print(activecamera)
```

And yes I'm old timer newbie!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
active_camera = scene.camera

if active_camera:
    print(active_camera.name)
else:
    print("No Active Camera Selected")
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, that worked as I wanted. I guess I was asking for to much info by listing the bpy.data and got he result that I was asking for and not what I wanted. Thanks batFINGER.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want the name to display.

If you print the object of camera, python will treat it as an object and print the structure by default. You can retrieve the `name`(`class <str>`) properties inside the camera object, which is the name of the object in outliner panel.

`print(activecamera.name)` should display the desired thing.

[image]
[image]

In 1 line:

```
print(activecamera.name if activecamera else "No Active Camera Selected")
```

Also, if you delete the camera inside the script, activecamera might point to an invalid object.